# grub2 on my embedded Board Corrupted, entered into grub rescue mode

Tags: grub2

I am working on a Intel board with centos running on it. My grub2 got corrupted. 
    and entering into grub rescue mode

**Problem** -
 whenever I reboot the device.
    grub rescue contains below info, when I do ls

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)

 grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)/
 ./ ../ grub/ grub2/ .vmlinuz-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.hmac System.map-3.10.0-123.el
 7.x86_64 config-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 symvers-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.gz vmlinuz-3
 .10.0-123.el7.x86_64 initramfs-0-rescue-7045993b43374642b45420e6c103adc8.img vml
 inuz-0-rescue-7045993b43374642b45420e6c103adc8 initrd-plymouth.img initramfs-3.1
 0.0-123.el7.x86_64.img initramfs-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64kdump.img


grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos3)/
./ ../ boot/ dev/ proc/ run/ sys/ etc/ root/ tmp/ var/ usr/ bin sbin lib lib64 
home/ media/ mnt/ opt/ srv/ .autorelabel .readahead
```

How can I solve this issue.
    Thanks in advance

Comment: You may ask this question on **Super User** community to get more helpful answers. @anish

Answer (score 0):

### command line Interface:

set boot=(hd0, msdos1)
set prefix=(hd0, msdos1)/boot/grub
insmod normal

### normal

instruction:
give command ls
It will show your partitions like (hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
then type ls and your partitions one by one 
Example: ls (hd0,msdos3)
If it says, Its not your file system, that means, that is not your linux partition. Search one by one. You linux partition will show you a file system like ext2
Use the partition name like (hd0,your linus partition) in command.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
The solution is simple. Type in either of the following:

```
1. exit

 OR

2. Exit
```

I do not remember the exact one, but what happened next was that either it went to UEFI, where I changed the boot order and delete it after entering Windows, or I was given the option to choose which disk to boot from, where I choose the partition with Windows.

No installation or recovery of Windows was required.